# How to Select an out parameter from a MySql Procedure in .net

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, mysqlcommand

Assume we have a stored procedure like so

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CopyValue(IN src INT, OUT dest INT)
BEGIN
    SET dest = src;
END
```

I want to call this from a .net app (assume connection etc created successfully)

`var sql = "call CopyValue(100, @destValue); select @destValue as Results;";`

The string in the above statement works perfectly well when called in MySql Workbench.

However this - obviously - fails with "MySqlException: Parameter '@destValue' must be defined" when executed on a `MySqlCommand` object in .net

How do I arrange this statement so I can capture an output parameter from an existing procedure?

**NB**: I'm running against MySql 5.6, which I can't upgrade at this time.

**NB** Calling the procedure directly with `CommandType.StoredProcedure` goes against company guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for a well-written problem statement with a minimal reproducible example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague (who wishes to remain anonymous) has answered this perfectly. Essentially put backticks ` after the @ and at the end of the variable name e.g.

```
@`MyParam`
```

A fully working example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using var con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; User Id=...;Password=...;Initial Catalog=...");
    con.Open();
    using var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "call CopyValue2(100, @`v2`); select @`v2` as Results;";
    using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
        Console.WriteLine($"Copied Value {reader.GetInt64(0)}");
}
```

Thanks OG :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, user-defined variables aren't allowed in SQL statements by MySQL Connector/NET. You can relax this restriction by adding `AllowUserVariables=true;` to your connection string. No modifications to your SQL or how you're executing the `MySqlCommand` should be necessary.

For information about *why* this is the default, you can read the research on this [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) issue (which also has the same default behaviour, but a much better error message that will tell you how to solve the problem): https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/194